# ¿Cuál es la traducción correcta de «número aval»?

Tags: traducción, inglés, terminología, matemáticas

Este término, *número aval*, es empleado en teoría de números. He intentado utilizar el traductor automático de Google, Bing y similares pero lo traduce de forma incorrecta como su significado de ‘garantía’ y no es exactamente lo que estoy buscando.

Lo más aproximado que he encontrado es *número de Midy*, pero esto tampoco es exactamente el término correcto.

¿Cuál sería su traducción en inglés? Mi duda tambien aplica para los términos en plural como *números avales* y *número aval exacto*.

Dado que es una terminología que se da en matemáticas no sé dónde más buscar. ¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar qué significa "número aval" en teoría de números? Nunca había oído esta expresión antes de hoy.

Answer (score 2):

El término **número aval** no parece ser un término estándar en matemáticas, porque solo lo encuentro en algunos blogs y vídeos de Youtube (no en libros de matemáticas ni en el [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/aval)). Parece ser una generalización del término **número decimal** (que sí que está en el [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/decimal?m=form)) cuando la base de numeración no es necesariamente 10. Por ejemplo, cuando escribimos

- 1/4=0.25

llamamos **fracción** a 1/4 y llamamos **número decimal** a 0.25. Pero si escribimos en base 8:

- 1/4=0.2 (base 8)

seguimos llamando **fracción** a 1/4, y ahora llamamos **número octal** a 0.2. El término **número aval** engloba los nombres "decimal", "octal", binario", etc. en una sola palabra, que describe la forma de representar un número usando dos series de cifras separadas por un punto.

El objetivo de este sitio no es traducir al inglés, pero esta misma pregunta ha sido formulada en [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/93315/495620), y allí se dan varias sugerencias como "numeral in radix point notation", "base-p expansion of a number", o "binary/ternary/octal fraction".

Comment: ¿ *Parte fraccionaria* ?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' supongo que en el "número decimal" 7.33, la parte fraccionaria es solo 0.33. Yo entiendo que "número aval" es 7.33 también. Pero no estoy seguro.

Comment: Number represented in [base *n* number system](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/NumberBases.html)?